# Website URL not creating in correct format

Tags: c#

I am developing a page in asp.net with c#. On this page I have a grid view control which showing customer name and its website. 
The problem is that when i click on this website address then the URL so created is not in the correct format.

For example, if my customer name is Yahoo and its website address is www.yahoo.com. Then on clicking the website link error will occurred.

My code on aspx page:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="linkWebsite" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Website") %>'
                 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My page URL is:
http://localhost:4294/ReadyToCode/Admin/ManageCustomer.aspx

then the website URL will become 
http://localhost:4294/ReadyToCode/Admin/www.yahoo.com

how to get only www.yahoo.com ?

Please help me...

Comment: The URL is being created by getWebSite(Eval("Website")) - so how about posting the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website","http://{0}") %>'
```